Issue mapping baked material for LEGO geometry nodes
I'm trying to recreate the Lego version of this beach ball object, which has been baked (as geometry nodes cannot do multiple materials as far as I know).
The baked material is fine when not using the geometry nodes as you can see here:

However, when I use my geometry nodes, the UV map appears all wrong (even though I unwrapped the object before baking (btw, I am using SimpleBake add on). I know you are supposed to use instancing for the material, but nonetheless it won't distribute the material properly:

Any ideas as to why this error might be happening? FYI I am using 4.1.1 if that helps.
Here is a link to the .blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uHhGB_Wo2dY40ZQLM0HKHBXm2D6t7iZt/view?usp=sharing

You have stored UV map as float, change it to vector:


That worked! Thanks so much!
